# Convert \ud83d\udc7b back to  in python

Tags: python

How can I decode the javascript code back to the ghost emoji in python

I tried putting that directly in print, but yeah did not work

tried even:

```
import emoji
print(emoji.emojize("\uD83D\uDC7B"))
```

both resulting in:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't encode characters in position 0-1: surrogates not allowed
```

Comment: In the interest of a [asking a complete question](/help/how-to-ask), what did you try and what did it do?

Comment: Why not just use `""`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `str.encode` method to get this, as this is a surrogate pair, you might want to try:

```py
"\ud83d\udc7b".encode("utf-16", "surrogatepass").decode("utf-16")
```

You will need a terminal that supports this.